# DATE_TRUNC Starting on Sunday for SQL presto (Athena)

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, amazon-athena, presto

For as simple as this question may sound, I have not been able to find a straight forward solution. I am using AWS Athena, which is a presto engine to my knowledge.

I have variable 'created_at' which is a TIMESTAMP.
How can I get `DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)` to start in SUNDAY instead of MONDAY ?

I've seen documentation concerning %V or %X as possible solutions, but not sure where in the function to introduce this, that is, if it is the proper solution.

Essentially I want to count sales by week starting on SUNDAY ending on SATURDAY , I will be grouping by weeK

```
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('week', created_at)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use them in [`date_format`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_format) function: `date_format(created_at, '%X%V')` (and use the result to group), but unfortunately they are not supported by presto at the moment.

As a workaround you can just add one day:

```sql
select week(created_at + interval '1' day)
```

Comment: Thank you !
Yeah, I had read in the documentation '%X%V' was not supported, which is super unfortunate considering how widely used athena and redshift are becoming :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
CAST(DATE_ADD('day', -DATE_DIFF('day', DATE_ADD('day', -1, DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', created_at)), created_at), created_at) AS VARCHAR) AS week_start_sunday
```